# jsf 2.0 Expression language brackets not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jstl, el

I have this attribute in my h:commandButton

```
disabled="#{ not ( ( nodeChild.children == null or empty nodeChild.children ) and ( not setupManager.currentTerminals ) ) }"
```

If it renders `disabled="false"` everything works but the other throws this exception

```
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert [] of type class java.util.ArrayList to class java.lang.Boolean
```

What is the best way of writing the above condition?
Can I use the brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#{setupManager.currentTerminals}` is apparently returning an `ArrayList` and thus the expression `#{not setupManager.currentTerminals}` will fail because it's not a `Boolean`. Use the `not empty` instead of `not`. Here's a rewrite (note that `empty` covers `null` as well, you don't need to do a nullcheck before).

```
disabled="#{not empty nodeChild.children and not empty setupManager.currentTerminals}"
```